# Transforming a Default Namespace Declaration from XSLT to XML

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

My first post ever. Before I start, I will admit that I hacked through my XSLT definition. And I don't have a good understanding of namespaces.

I am using an XSLT to tranform an XML. I need a default namespace to appear in my resultant XML. The default namespace is:

xmlns="http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/2005fd"

My transformation worked fine without this namespace. But when I add this to my XSLT, I end up in an empty xmlns="" attributes with my node names. I have read many posts, they all tell you to add a prefix to the namespace. But I can't add one. I need my namespace to be displayed in the xml as I showed above.

Here's the XSLT header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns="http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/2005fd"
>
<!-- Format for output document -->
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Find the ROOT element and data underneath it -->
<xsl:template match="ROOT">


    <!-- BMEcat XML output -->
    <BMECAT version="2005">

        <!-- Header information -->
        <HEADER>


            <!-- Copy the BUYER nodes -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="BUYER"/>
```

It produces the right header for the XML. However, it affects the node names with the empty attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BMECAT version="2005" 
  xmlns="http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/2005fd" 
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
>
  <HEADER>
    <BUYER xmlns="">
      <BUYER_NAME>XYZ</BUYER_NAME>
    </BUYER>
```

How do I get rid of the empty xmlns attribute, while keeping the namespace in the xml output header without a prefix?

Thanks all

Here's the complete template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns="http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/2005fd"
    >
    <!-- Format for output document -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- ISO 639-2 Lanugate code lookup -->
     <xsl:variable name="langMap">
    <entry key="EN">eng</entry>
    <entry key="DE">deu</entry>
    <entry key="ES">spa</entry>
        <entry key="FR">fra</entry>
        <entry key="IT">ita</entry>
        <entry key="JA">jpn</entry>
        <entry key="PT">por</entry>
        <entry key="RU">rus</entry>
        <entry key="ZH">zho</entry>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- Find the ROOT element and data underneath it -->
    <xsl:template match="ROOT">

        <!-- Declare a variable for date -->
        <xsl:param name="date"><xsl:value-of select="timestamp" /></xsl:param>

        <!-- BMEcat XML output -->
        <BMECAT version="2005">

            <!-- Header information -->
            <HEADER>
                <CATALOG>
                    <LANGUAGE>eng</LANGUAGE>
                    <CATALOG_ID>001.001</CATALOG_ID>
                    <CATALOG_VERSION>001.027</CATALOG_VERSION>
                    <CATALOG_NAME>Mersen-BMEcat</CATALOG_NAME>
                    <DATETIME type="generation_date">
                        <DATE>
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($date,'T')" />
                        </DATE>
                    </DATETIME>
                    <TERRITORY>GB</TERRITORY>
                    <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
                </CATALOG>

                <!-- Copy the BUYER nodes -->
                <xsl:template match="BUYER">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:template>



                <!-- Copy the SUPPLIER nodes -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="SUPPLIER"/>

                <!-- Copy the MIME_INFO nodes -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="MIME_INFO"/>

                <USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS>
                    <UDX.EDXF.VERSION>3.1</UDX.EDXF.VERSION>
                </USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS>
            </HEADER>

            <!-- Product Information Section -->
            <T_NEW_CATALOG>

                <!-- Cycle for each of the PRODUCT_ITEM in the output -->
                <xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/PRODUCT_ITEM">

                    <!-- Create a PRODUCT Element -->
                    <PRODUCT mode="new">

                        <!-- PRODUCT level propertes -->
                        <SUPPLIER_PID><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_NUMBER" /></SUPPLIER_PID>

                        <!-- PRODUCT DETAILS properties-->
                        <PRODUCT_DETAILS>

                            <DESCRIPTION_SHORT><xsl:value-of select="SHORT_DESCRIPTION__80MAX_EN" /></DESCRIPTION_SHORT>

                            <!-- Code for multilingual DESCRIPTION_LONG, change the first two lines for other properties -->
                            <xsl:variable name="tagName">LONG_DESCRIPTION_</xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:variable name="elemName">DESCRIPTION_LONG</xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:for-each select="node()[starts-with(name(), $tagName)]">
                                <xsl:variable name="nodename" >
                                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:variable name = "langCode2" select="substring-after($nodename,$tagName)"></xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:variable name = "langCode3" select="msxsl:node-set($langMap)/entry[@key=$langCode2]"/>
                                <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="lang"><xsl:value-of select="$langCode3" /></xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:for-each>

                            <!-- Properties -->
                            <xsl:if test="EAN_UPC_CODE != ''">
                                <INTERNATIONAL_PID type="GTIN"><xsl:value-of select="EAN_UPC_CODE" /></INTERNATIONAL_PID>
                            </xsl:if>   
                            <xsl:if test="REF_NO != ''">
                                <SUPPLIER_ALT_PID><xsl:value-of select="REF_NO" /></SUPPLIER_ALT_PID>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="CATALOGUE_NO_ != ''">
                                <MANUFACTURER_TYPE_DESCR><xsl:value-of select="CATALOGUE_NO_" /></MANUFACTURER_TYPE_DESCR>
                            </xsl:if>

                            <!-- Code for multilingual KEYWORD, change the first two lines for other properties -->
                            <xsl:variable name="tagName2">KEYWORD_</xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:variable name="elemName2">KEYWORD</xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:for-each select="node()[starts-with(name(), $tagName2)]">
                                <xsl:variable name="nodename" >
                                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:variable name = "langCode2" select="substring-after($nodename,$tagName2)"></xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:variable name = "langCode3" select="msxsl:node-set($langMap)/entry[@key=$langCode2]"/>
                                <xsl:element name="{$elemName2}">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="lang"><xsl:value-of select="$langCode3" /></xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:for-each>

                            <PRODUCT_STATUS type="new">New</PRODUCT_STATUS>

                        </PRODUCT_DETAILS>

                        <!-- PRODUCT FEATURES properties-->
                        <PRODUCT_FEATURES>
                            <REFERENCE_FEATURE_SYSTEM_NAME>ETIM-6.0</REFERENCE_FEATURE_SYSTEM_NAME>
                            <REFERENCE_FEATURE_GROUP_ID><xsl:value-of select="ETIM_CLASS" /></REFERENCE_FEATURE_GROUP_ID>
                             <xsl:for-each select="FEATURE">
                                 <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </PRODUCT_FEATURES>

                        <!-- PRODUCT ORDER Details-->
                        <PRODUCT_ORDER_DETAILS>
                            <ORDER_UNIT>C62</ORDER_UNIT>
                            <CONTENT_UNIT>C62</CONTENT_UNIT>
                            <NO_CU_PER_OU>1</NO_CU_PER_OU>
                            <PRICE_QUANTITY>1</PRICE_QUANTITY>
                            <QUANTITY_MIN><xsl:value-of select="SELL_PACK_QUANTITY" /></QUANTITY_MIN>
                            <QUANTITY_INTERVAL><xsl:value-of select="SELL_PACK_QUANTITY" /></QUANTITY_INTERVAL>
                        </PRODUCT_ORDER_DETAILS>

                        <!-- PRODUCT ORDER Details-->
                        <PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS>
                            <DATETIME type="valid_start_date">
                                <DATE><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($date,'T')" /></DATE>
              </DATETIME>
                            <PRODUCT_PRICE price_type="nrp">
                                 <PRICE_AMOUNT>1</PRICE_AMOUNT>
                            </PRODUCT_PRICE>
                        </PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS>

                        <!-- MIME INFO -->
                        <xsl:for-each select="MIME_INFO">
                            <MIME_INFO>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
                            </MIME_INFO>
                        </xsl:for-each> 

                        <!-- USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS -->
                        <USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS>
                            <UDX.EDXF.MANUFACTURER_ACRONYM>Mersen</UDX.EDXF.MANUFACTURER_ACRONYM>
                            <UDX.EDXF.DESCRIPTION_VERY_SHORT><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_DESCRIPTION__ERP_EN" /></UDX.EDXF.DESCRIPTION_VERY_SHORT>
                            <UDX.EDXF.BRAND_NAME><xsl:value-of select="BRAND_NAME" /></UDX.EDXF.BRAND_NAME>
                            <UDX.EDXF.PACKING_UNITS>
                                <UDX.EDXF.PACKING_UNIT>
                                    <UDX.EDXF.QUANTITY_MIN><xsl:value-of select="SELL_PACK_QUANTITY" /></UDX.EDXF.QUANTITY_MIN>
                                    <UDX.EDXF.QUANTITY_MAX><xsl:value-of select="SELL_PACK_QUANTITY" /></UDX.EDXF.QUANTITY_MAX>
                                    <UDX.EDXF.PACKING_UNIT_CODE><xsl:value-of select="SELL_PACK_QUANTITY_UOM" /></UDX.EDXF.PACKING_UNIT_CODE>
                                    <UDX.EDXF.WEIGHT><xsl:value-of select="SELL_PACK_WEIGHT" /></UDX.EDXF.WEIGHT>
                                    <UDX.EDXF.LENGTH><xsl:value-of select="SELL_PACK_LENGTH" /></UDX.EDXF.LENGTH>
                                    <UDX.EDXF.WIDTH><xsl:value-of select="SELL_PACK_WIDTH" /></UDX.EDXF.WIDTH>
                                    <UDX.EDXF.DEPTH><xsl:value-of select="SELL_PACK_HEIGHT" /></UDX.EDXF.DEPTH>
                                    <UDX.EDXF.GTIN><xsl:value-of select="GTIN_SELL_PACK" /></UDX.EDXF.GTIN>
                                </UDX.EDXF.PACKING_UNIT>
                            </UDX.EDXF.PACKING_UNITS>
                            <UDX.EDXF.PRODUCT_LOGISTIC_DETAILS>
                                <UDX.EDXF.NETWEIGHT><xsl:value-of select="PRODUCT_WEIGHT" /></UDX.EDXF.NETWEIGHT>
                            </UDX.EDXF.PRODUCT_LOGISTIC_DETAILS>
                            <UDX.EDXF.REACH>
                                <UDX.EDXF.REACH.LISTDATE><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($date,'T')" /></UDX.EDXF.REACH.LISTDATE>
                                <UDX.EDXF.REACH.INFO>no data</UDX.EDXF.REACH.INFO>
                            </UDX.EDXF.REACH>
                        </USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS>

                        <!-- Product Logistic Details -->                   
                        <PRODUCT_LOGISTIC_DETAILS>
                            <CUSTOMS_TARIFF_NUMBER>
                                <CUSTOMS_NUMBER><xsl:value-of select="EU_CUSTOMS_CODE" /></CUSTOMS_NUMBER>
                            </CUSTOMS_TARIFF_NUMBER>
                            <COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN><xsl:value-of select="COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN" /></COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN>
                        </PRODUCT_LOGISTIC_DETAILS>
                    </PRODUCT>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </T_NEW_CATALOG>
        </BMECAT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the raw XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT>
  <timestamp>2017-01-24T16:04:37</timestamp>
  <BUYER>
    <BUYER_NAME>XYZ</BUYER_NAME>
  </BUYER>
  <SUPPLIER>
    <SUPPLIER_ID type="duns">328546853</SUPPLIER_ID>
    <SUPPLIER_NAME>Mersen</SUPPLIER_NAME>
    <ADDRESS type="supplier">
      <CONTACT>Susan Tichy</CONTACT>
      <STREET>Lienfeldergasse 31-33</STREET>
      <ZIP>1160</ZIP>
      <CITY>WIEN</CITY>
      <COUNTRY>Austria</COUNTRY>
      <EMAIL>susanne.tichy@mersen.com</EMAIL>
      <URL>www.mersen.com</URL>
    </ADDRESS>
  </SUPPLIER>
  <PRODUCT_ITEM>
    <ITEM_NUMBER>A480T5E</ITEM_NUMBER>
    <BRAND_NAME>Mersen</BRAND_NAME>
    <COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN>MX</COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN>
    <ETIM_CLASS>EC000055</ETIM_CLASS>
    <LONG_DESCRIPTION_EN>Mersen PT fuses are current-limiting fuses with high interrupting rating, used for the primary winding protection of potential transformer. They are small dimension ferrule type fuses and mount in standard clips. Current ratings are from 0.25A to 5A.</LONG_DESCRIPTION_EN>
    <LONG_DESCRIPTION_FR>French description</LONG_DESCRIPTION_FR>
    <LONG_DESCRIPTION_DE>Mersen PT fuses are current-limiting fuses with high interrupting rating, used for the primary winding protection of potential transformer. They are small dimension ferrule type fuses and mount in standard clips. Current ratings are from 0.25A to 5A.</LONG_DESCRIPTION_DE>
    <LONG_DESCRIPTION_IT>Mersen PT fuses are current-limiting fuses with high interrupting rating, used for the primary winding protection of potential transformer. They are small dimension ferrule type fuses and mount in standard clips. Current ratings are from 0.25A to 5A.</LONG_DESCRIPTION_IT>
    <LONG_DESCRIPTION_JA>Mersen PT fuses are current-limiting fuses with high interrupting rating, used for the primary winding protection of potential transformer. They are small dimension ferrule type fuses and mount in standard clips. Current ratings are from 0.25A to 5A.</LONG_DESCRIPTION_JA>
    <PRODUCT_BRAND>Amp-Trap®</PRODUCT_BRAND>
    <SUPPORT_BRAND>Ferraz Shawmut</SUPPORT_BRAND>
    <PRODUCT_WEIGHT>0.1814368</PRODUCT_WEIGHT>
    <PRODUCT_WEIGHT_UOM>KGM</PRODUCT_WEIGHT_UOM>
    <SELL_PACK_DESCRIPTION>Box</SELL_PACK_DESCRIPTION>
    <SELL_PACK_HEIGHT>0.06985</SELL_PACK_HEIGHT>
    <SELL_PACK_HEIGHT_UOM>MTR</SELL_PACK_HEIGHT_UOM>
    <SELL_PACK_LENGTH>0.2032</SELL_PACK_LENGTH>
    <SELL_PACK_LENGTH_UOM>MTR</SELL_PACK_LENGTH_UOM>
    <SELL_PACK_WIDTH>0.1016</SELL_PACK_WIDTH>
    <SELL_PACK_WIDTH_UOM>MTR</SELL_PACK_WIDTH_UOM>
    <SELL_PACK_QUANTITY>2</SELL_PACK_QUANTITY>
    <SELL_PACK_QUANTITY_UOM>C62</SELL_PACK_QUANTITY_UOM>
    <SELL_PACK_WEIGHT>0.38101728</SELL_PACK_WEIGHT>
    <SELL_PACK_WEIGHT_UOM>KGM</SELL_PACK_WEIGHT_UOM>
    <FEATURE>
      <FNAME PIM_name="AMPERE_RATING">EF000227</FNAME>
      <FVALUE PIM_value="5">5</FVALUE>
      <FUNIT PIM_unit="A">EU570459</FUNIT>
    </FEATURE>
    <ARTICLE_NO>M217959B</ARTICLE_NO>
    <CATALOGUE_NO_>M217959A</CATALOGUE_NO_>
    <EAN_UPC_CODE>068938800574</EAN_UPC_CODE>
    <EU_CUSTOMS_CODE>85351000</EU_CUSTOMS_CODE>
    <GTIN_SELL_PACK>30068938800575</GTIN_SELL_PACK>
    <ITEM_DESCRIPTION__ERP_EN>4800V E-RATED FUSE 5E</ITEM_DESCRIPTION__ERP_EN>
    <ITEM_DESCRIPTION__ERP_FR>4800V E-RATED FUSE 5E</ITEM_DESCRIPTION__ERP_FR>
    <ITEM_DESCRIPTION__ERP_DE>4800V E-RATED FUSE 5E</ITEM_DESCRIPTION__ERP_DE>
    <ITEM_DESCRIPTION__ERP_IT>4800V E-RATED FUSE 5E</ITEM_DESCRIPTION__ERP_IT>
    <ITEM_DESCRIPTION__ERP_JA>4800V E-RATED FUSE 5E</ITEM_DESCRIPTION__ERP_JA>
    <MINIMUM_QUANTITY_PER_ORDER>2</MINIMUM_QUANTITY_PER_ORDER>
    <ORDER_MULTIPLE>2</ORDER_MULTIPLE>
    <REF_NO>M217959</REF_NO>
    <SHORT_DESCRIPTION__80MAX_EN>4800V E-RATED FUSE 5E - short description</SHORT_DESCRIPTION__80MAX_EN>
    <SHORT_DESCRIPTION__80MAX_FR>4800V E-RATED FUSE 5E - short description</SHORT_DESCRIPTION__80MAX_FR>
    <SHORT_DESCRIPTION__80MAX_DE>4800V E-RATED FUSE 5E - short description</SHORT_DESCRIPTION__80MAX_DE>
    <SHORT_DESCRIPTION__80MAX_IT>4800V E-RATED FUSE 5E - short description</SHORT_DESCRIPTION__80MAX_IT>
    <SHORT_DESCRIPTION__80MAX_JA>4800V E-RATED FUSE 5E - short description</SHORT_DESCRIPTION__80MAX_JA>
    <KEYWORD_EN>English Keyword1</KEYWORD_EN>
    <KEYWORD_EN>English Keyword2</KEYWORD_EN>
    <KEYWORD_DE>German Keyword1</KEYWORD_DE>
    <KEYWORD_IT>Italian Keyword 3</KEYWORD_IT>
  </PRODUCT_ITEM>
</ROOT>
```

And here's the desired output. Please note the  tags without the empty attribute.

A secondary issue is the attributes printing with the ,  and  elements. I don't want the attributes to get copied. This output is showing how it should be.

<

```
BUYER>
        <BUYER_NAME>XYZ</BUYER_NAME>
      </BUYER>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <BMECAT version="2005" xmlns="http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/2005fd" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
      <HEADER>
        <CATALOG>
          <LANGUAGE>eng</LANGUAGE>
          <CATALOG_ID>001.001</CATALOG_ID>
          <CATALOG_VERSION>001.027</CATALOG_VERSION>
          <CATALOG_NAME>Mersen-BMEcat</CATALOG_NAME>
          <DATETIME type="generation_date">
            <DATE>2017-01-24</DATE>
          </DATETIME>
          <TERRITORY>GB</TERRITORY>
          <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
        </CATALOG>
        <ROOT>
          <BUYER>
            <BUYER_NAME>XYZ</BUYER_NAME>
          </BUYER>
        </ROOT>
        <SUPPLIER>
          <SUPPLIER_ID type="duns">328546853</SUPPLIER_ID>
          <SUPPLIER_NAME>Mersen</SUPPLIER_NAME>
          <ADDRESS type="supplier">
            <CONTACT>Susan Tichy</CONTACT>
            <STREET>Lienfeldergasse 31-33</STREET>
            <ZIP>1160</ZIP>
            <CITY>WIEN</CITY>
            <COUNTRY>Austria</COUNTRY>
            <EMAIL>susanne.tichy@mersen.com</EMAIL>
            <URL>www.mersen.com</URL>
          </ADDRESS>
        </SUPPLIER>
        <USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS>
          <UDX.EDXF.VERSION>3.1</UDX.EDXF.VERSION>
        </USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS>
      </HEADER>
      <T_NEW_CATALOG>
        <PRODUCT mode="new">
          <SUPPLIER_PID>A480T5E</SUPPLIER_PID>
          <PRODUCT_DETAILS>
            <DESCRIPTION_SHORT>4800V E-RATED FUSE 5E - short description</DESCRIPTION_SHORT>
            <DESCRIPTION_LONG lang="">Mersen PT fuses are current-limiting fuses with high interrupting rating, used for the primary winding protection of potential transformer. They are small dimension ferrule type fuses and mount in standard clips. Current ratings are from 0.25A to 5A.</DESCRIPTION_LONG>
            <DESCRIPTION_LONG lang="">French description</DESCRIPTION_LONG>
            <DESCRIPTION_LONG lang="">Mersen PT fuses are current-limiting fuses with high interrupting rating, used for the primary winding protection of potential transformer. They are small dimension ferrule type fuses and mount in standard clips. Current ratings are from 0.25A to 5A.</DESCRIPTION_LONG>
            <DESCRIPTION_LONG lang="">Mersen PT fuses are current-limiting fuses with high interrupting rating, used for the primary winding protection of potential transformer. They are small dimension ferrule type fuses and mount in standard clips. Current ratings are from 0.25A to 5A.</DESCRIPTION_LONG>
            <DESCRIPTION_LONG lang="">Mersen PT fuses are current-limiting fuses with high interrupting rating, used for the primary winding protection of potential transformer. They are small dimension ferrule type fuses and mount in standard clips. Current ratings are from 0.25A to 5A.</DESCRIPTION_LONG>
            <INTERNATIONAL_PID type="GTIN">068938800574</INTERNATIONAL_PID>
            <SUPPLIER_ALT_PID>M217959</SUPPLIER_ALT_PID>
            <MANUFACTURER_TYPE_DESCR>M217959A</MANUFACTURER_TYPE_DESCR>
            <KEYWORD lang="">English Keyword1</KEYWORD>
            <KEYWORD lang="">English Keyword2</KEYWORD>
            <KEYWORD lang="">German Keyword1</KEYWORD>
            <KEYWORD lang="">Italian Keyword 3</KEYWORD>
            <PRODUCT_STATUS type="new">New</PRODUCT_STATUS>
          </PRODUCT_DETAILS>
          <PRODUCT_FEATURES>
            <REFERENCE_FEATURE_SYSTEM_NAME>ETIM-6.0</REFERENCE_FEATURE_SYSTEM_NAME>
            <REFERENCE_FEATURE_GROUP_ID>EC000055</REFERENCE_FEATURE_GROUP_ID>
            <FEATURE>
              <FNAME>EF000227</FNAME>
              <FVALUE>5</FVALUE>
              <FUNIT>EU570459</FUNIT>
            </FEATURE>
          </PRODUCT_FEATURES>
          <PRODUCT_ORDER_DETAILS>
            <ORDER_UNIT>C62</ORDER_UNIT>
            <CONTENT_UNIT>C62</CONTENT_UNIT>
            <NO_CU_PER_OU>1</NO_CU_PER_OU>
            <PRICE_QUANTITY>1</PRICE_QUANTITY>
            <QUANTITY_MIN>2</QUANTITY_MIN>
            <QUANTITY_INTERVAL>2</QUANTITY_INTERVAL>
          </PRODUCT_ORDER_DETAILS>
          <PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS>
            <DATETIME type="valid_start_date">
              <DATE>2017-01-24</DATE>
            </DATETIME>
            <PRODUCT_PRICE price_type="nrp">
              <PRICE_AMOUNT>1</PRICE_AMOUNT>
            </PRODUCT_PRICE>
          </PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS>
          <USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS>
            <UDX.EDXF.MANUFACTURER_ACRONYM>Mersen</UDX.EDXF.MANUFACTURER_ACRONYM>
            <UDX.EDXF.DESCRIPTION_VERY_SHORT>4800V E-RATED FUSE 5E</UDX.EDXF.DESCRIPTION_VERY_SHORT>
            <UDX.EDXF.BRAND_NAME>Mersen</UDX.EDXF.BRAND_NAME>
            <UDX.EDXF.PACKING_UNITS>
              <UDX.EDXF.PACKING_UNIT>
                <UDX.EDXF.QUANTITY_MIN>2</UDX.EDXF.QUANTITY_MIN>
                <UDX.EDXF.QUANTITY_MAX>2</UDX.EDXF.QUANTITY_MAX>
                <UDX.EDXF.PACKING_UNIT_CODE>C62</UDX.EDXF.PACKING_UNIT_CODE>
                <UDX.EDXF.WEIGHT>0.38101728</UDX.EDXF.WEIGHT>
                <UDX.EDXF.LENGTH>0.2032</UDX.EDXF.LENGTH>
                <UDX.EDXF.WIDTH>0.1016</UDX.EDXF.WIDTH>
                <UDX.EDXF.DEPTH>0.06985</UDX.EDXF.DEPTH>
                <UDX.EDXF.GTIN>30068938800575</UDX.EDXF.GTIN>
              </UDX.EDXF.PACKING_UNIT>
            </UDX.EDXF.PACKING_UNITS>
            <UDX.EDXF.PRODUCT_LOGISTIC_DETAILS>
              <UDX.EDXF.NETWEIGHT>0.1814368</UDX.EDXF.NETWEIGHT>
            </UDX.EDXF.PRODUCT_LOGISTIC_DETAILS>
            <UDX.EDXF.REACH>
              <UDX.EDXF.REACH.LISTDATE>2017-01-24</UDX.EDXF.REACH.LISTDATE>
              <UDX.EDXF.REACH.INFO>no data</UDX.EDXF.REACH.INFO>
            </UDX.EDXF.REACH>
          </USER_DEFINED_EXTENSIONS>
          <PRODUCT_LOGISTIC_DETAILS>
            <CUSTOMS_TARIFF_NUMBER>
              <CUSTOMS_NUMBER>85351000</CUSTOMS_NUMBER>
            </CUSTOMS_TARIFF_NUMBER>
            <COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN>MX</COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN>
          </PRODUCT_LOGISTIC_DETAILS>
        </PRODUCT>
      </T_NEW_CATALOG>
    </BMECAT>
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, rather than snippets. That means an example of the XML input,  your full stylesheet, and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Comment: @michael is right. We need the complete xml, xslt and simulated desired output. With that, I think this is an easy one to fix.

Comment: If the `BUYER` element in the input is in no namespace and in the result you want it to be in the namespace `http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/2005fd` then you can't copy that element, instead you need to transform it to the new namespace.

Comment: Complete code added

Comment: @MartinHonnen . So by transform you mean?

Comment: @KaveAdam Your transform should produce the desired result. To use a universal namespace for your output XML file, you just need to declared it in the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element as `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns="http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/2005fd"
    >` which you have already done. It produces the desired output: http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLH. We need more info on the issue with the attributes.

Comment: Note that there's a category error in the title of your question. You can't transform "namespace declarations" using XSLT, because namespace declarations aren't part of the data model. XSLT doesn't transform raw XML, it transforms the trees created by parsing XML, and namespace declarations exist only in raw XML, not in the XDM tree representation.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you don't want the namespace (un)declaration on

```
<BUYER xmlns="">
```

That means, you want the BUYER element in the result document to be in namespace http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/2005fd. But the BUYER element in the source document is in no namespace. So the BUYER element in the result document is different from the BUYER element in the source document: it's not an exact copy, so you can't produce it using `<xsl:copy-of>`. Copying an element will never change the name of the element (and the namespace is an essential part of the name).

To change the namespace of elements in the source document you need to use something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="rename">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/2005fd">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Michael, thanks for your response. I have seen your suggestion in many places. However, I just don't know how to apply it to my template. I have tried the "apply-templates" but I get strange results due to my lack of understanding. I am doing a "match" at the root level. How do I do a "match" at the element level? Where does this code fit in my XSLT?

Comment: @KaveAdam, yes, I see a nested xsl:template has appeared in the XSLT code in your question which is clearly misplaced, suggesting you're still in the foothills of the learning curve. Being as I'm too busy to give a tutorial on the basics, I can only suggest you do some further reading before you do any more coding - find a book you get on with and work through the examples.

Comment: @MicahelKay Thank you for your response.